# entering points randomly inside the matrix

Tags: matlab, random

I would like to know how to enter points randomly inside a given specified(where the dimensions have been given) matrix in matlab.

Thought of doing like this but I am not sure
algorithm:

1) first generate the matrix of specified dimension using rand func.

```
l=input('enter the length:');
b=input('enter the bth:');
g=rand(b,l)
```

2) then using loop check for the dimension.

3) take some random number stored in p and enter it into the matrix

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear. From that I gather, you want to create a random matrix of some dimension, and then insert some number stored in a vector p at random locations in the matrix. Hopefully, you can get this working by using some (or all) of the code given below. As you can see, no loop is needed, and it automatically takes care of not inserting two numbers at the same posision.

```
%#Specify matrix dimensions
rows = 5;
cols = 8;

%#Create random matrix with values in (0,1)
M = rand(rows,cols);

%#Spesify parameters for numbers to insert and create p-vector
numbers_to_insert = 5;
number_range = [2 10];
p = randint(numbers_to_insert,1,number_range);

%#Select random locations to insert elements in p
rV = randperm(rows);
cV = randperm(cols);

%#Insert numbers into matrix by using 1 dimensional indexing
M(rV(1:numbers_to_insert)+(cV(1:numbers_to_insert)-1)*rows) = p;
```

Example result:

```
p =      5     5     8     9     3
rV=      1     3     4     5     2    
cV=      4     3     7     5     8     2     1     6 %#Only first 5 values used
M=
0.1656    0.7482    0.1524    5.0000    0.8173    0.8001    0.1455    0.1450
0.6020    0.4505    0.8258    0.1067    0.8687    0.4314    0.1361    3.0000
0.2630    0.0838    5.0000    0.9619    0.0844    0.9106    0.8693    0.6221
0.6541    0.2290    0.9961    0.0046    0.3998    0.1818    8.0000    0.3510
0.6892    0.9133    0.0782    0.7749    9.0000    0.2638    0.5499    0.5132
```